# Photo taken with camera does not contain any ALAsset metadata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

The weirdest thing is happening. I have an action sheet which gives the user the choice to either take a photo with the camera or choose one from the camera roll. Upon the UIImagePicker returning from selection I use the ALAssetsLibrary to determine the GPS information embedded in the photo. Choosing a photo from the camera roll works perfectly and I am able to retrieve the GPS information. However, taking a photo with the camera provides absolutely no GPS information, in fact I have no metadata at all. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Code below:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if([mediaType isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {        
        void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *) = ^(ALAsset *asset)
        {
            // get images metadata
            NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
            NSLog(@"Image Meta Data: %@",metadata);

            // get coords 
            CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
            NSLog(@"coordLat: %f , coordLon: %f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);

            // do more here - rest of code snipped to keep this question short

    };
    NSURL *assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:assetURL
             resultBlock:ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock
            failureBlock:^(NSError *error) 
            {
                // handle error 
            }];

    // rest of code snipped to keep this question short
```

As I explained, the following is outputted when using the camera.

```
2012-04-15 17:58:28.032 MyApp[511:707] Image Meta Data: (null)
2012-04-15 17:58:28.041 MyApp[511:707] coordLat: 0.000000 , coordLon: 0.000000
```

However, if I choose an existing photo, or exit out of the app, take a new photo with the camera, then go back into the app and select that photo from the camera roll i get the following output from NSLog.

```
2012-04-15 17:57:03.286 MyApp[511:707] Image Meta Data: {
ColorModel = RGB;
DPIHeight = 72;
DPIWidth = 72;
Depth = 8;
Orientation = 6;
PixelHeight = 1936;
PixelWidth = 2592;
"{Exif}" =     {
    ApertureValue = "2.970854";
    BrightnessValue = "2.886456";
    ColorSpace = 1;
    ComponentsConfiguration =         (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        0
    );
    DateTimeDigitized = "2012:04:15 17:24:02";
    DateTimeOriginal = "2012:04:15 17:24:02";
    ExifVersion =         (
        2,
        2,
        1
    );
    ExposureMode = 0;
    ExposureProgram = 2;
    ExposureTime = "0.06666667";
    FNumber = "2.8";
    Flash = 24;
    FlashPixVersion =         (
        1,
        0
    );
    FocalLength = "3.85";
    ISOSpeedRatings =         (
        80
    );
    MeteringMode = 5;
    PixelXDimension = 2592;
    PixelYDimension = 1936;
    SceneCaptureType = 0;
    SensingMethod = 2;
    Sharpness = 2;
    ShutterSpeedValue = "3.9112";
    SubjectArea =         (
        1295,
        967,
        699,
        696
    );
    WhiteBalance = 0;
};
"{GPS}" =     {
    Altitude = "14.9281";
    AltitudeRef = 0;
    ImgDirection = "107.4554";
    ImgDirectionRef = T;
    Latitude = "32.7366666666667";
    LatitudeRef = N;
    Longitude = "71.679";
    LongitudeRef = W;
    TimeStamp = "21:26:20.00";
};
"{TIFF}" =     {
    DateTime = "2012:04:15 17:24:02";
    Make = Apple;
    Model = "iPhone 4";
    Orientation = 6;
    ResolutionUnit = 2;
    Software = "5.0.1";
    XResolution = 72;
    YResolution = 72;
    "_YCbCrPositioning" = 1;
};
}
2012-04-15 17:57:03.302 MyApp[511:707] coordLat: 32.7366666666667 , coordLon: -71.679
```

PS - I'm using xCode 4.3 w/ ARC

Comment: A couple of answers that actually work are available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766394/get-exif-data-from-uiimage-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: I've followed those examples and I'm still hiving the same issue. Would you be able to post some code for me if you know specifically what my issue is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you turn on location services location services as the poster of accepted answer suggests? It looks that in some cases you have to add location meta data yourself. Which shouldn't be a problem if you have location services turned on.

Comment: Yes, location services is on and I can pull the lat/lon info from CLLocaionManager if I have too Its just weird that `asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata` returns absolutely no metadata when using the camera but using the EXACT same code on an image chosen from the camera roll does return metadata. I guess that until I figure this out I'll have to use the CLLocation information. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? My question is pretty much the same as yours (so if you have an answer, you can claim the bounty...) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302250/reading-the-gps-data-from-the-image-returned-by-the-camera-in-ios-iphone

Comment: Not exactly, I have two work arounds, both of which are not acceptable to you after reading your post. 1) save the photo to the camera roll, then pull it off and grab the GPS info from the metadata. I feel this is a major hack so I did not choose this method. 2) Start core location first, then launch the camera, after the image is taken use the coords returned from locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation. Neither options is ideal, if you get an answer on this please let me know. I'll keep checking your post, it seems that you've gotten a lot of views and responses thus far...

Comment: What about using the `NSDictionary *metadata = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];` in `didFinish...` in place of `NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;`? Give one try to it :)

Answer (score 13):

In `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`

Try this when saving the Photo

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage
                                 metadata:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]
                          completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"assetURL %@", assetURL);
    }];
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct solution. Save a photo taken from the camera to the camera roll and then you can use that as your assetURL to get ALAsset metadata!

Comment: ^Not really. While you will get the ALAsset from the assetURL in the completion block, valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation will return nil. The only real solution to this seems to be to use Core Location in the app.

Answer (score 0):

@Thanh-Cong Vo is right about how to save the image to Photo Album. And See what say the [Apples documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) about saving image to photo album

> To save a still image to the user’s Camera Roll album, call the
>   **[UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum)** function from within the body of the
>   **[imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController%3adidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo%3a)** method. To save a
>   movie to the user’s Camera Roll album, instead call the
>   **[UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW41)** function. These functions,
>   described in [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894), **save the image or movie only;
>   they do not save metadata.**
>
> Starting in iOS 4.0, you can save still-image metadata, along with a
>   still image, to the Camera Roll. To do this, use the
>   **[writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum%3ametadata%3acompletionBlock%3a)** method of the
>   Assets Library framework. See the description for the
>   [UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata) key.