# Reading the GPS data from the image returned by the camera in iOS iphone

Tags: ios, geolocation, gps, camera

I need to get the GPS coordinates of an image taken with the iOS device's camera. I do not care about the Camera Roll images, just the image taken with UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera.

I've read many stackoverflow answers, like [Get Exif data from UIImage - UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766394/get-exif-data-from-uiimage-uiimagepickercontroller), which either assumes you are using the AssetsLibrary framework, which doesn't seem to work on camera images, or use CoreLocaiton to get the latitude/longitude from the app itself, not from the image.

Using CoreLocation *is not an option*. That will not give me the coordinates when the shutter button was pressed. (With the CoreLocation based solutions, you either need to record the coords before you bring up the camera view or after, and of course if the device is moving the coordinates will be wrong. This method should work with a stationary device.)

I am iOS5 only, so I don't need to support older devices. This is also for a commercial product so I cannot use http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/.

So, what are my options for reading the GPS data from the image returned by the camera in iOS5? All I can think of right now is to save the image to Camera Roll and then use the AssetsLibrary, but that seems hokey.

Thanks!

---

Here's the code I wrote based on Caleb's answer.

```
    UIImage *image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *jpeg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0);
    CGImageSourceRef  source ;
    source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)jpeg, NULL);

    NSDictionary *metadataNew = (__bridge NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);  

    NSLog(@"%@",metadataNew);
```

and my Console shows:

```
    2012-04-26 14:15:37:137 ferret[2060:1799] {
        ColorModel = RGB;
        Depth = 8;
        Orientation = 6;
        PixelHeight = 1936;
        PixelWidth = 2592;
        "{Exif}" =     {
            ColorSpace = 1;
            PixelXDimension = 2592;
            PixelYDimension = 1936;
        };
        "{JFIF}" =     {
            DensityUnit = 0;
            JFIFVersion =         (
                1,
                1
            );
            XDensity = 1;
            YDensity = 1;
        };
        "{TIFF}" =     {
            Orientation = 6;
        };
    }
```

No latitude/longitude.

Comment: @SandyPatel Did you find the correct answer? How did you solve this? I don't want to use CoreLocation neither this framework  http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/ . Is it the only solution to save to camera roll and then extract it with the gps data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to leaving CoreLocation running when the camera is visible. Record each CCLocation into an array along with the time of the sample. When the photo comes back, find its time, then match the closest CClocation from the array.

Sounds kludgy but it will work.

Comment: kludgy, yes, but in the months since I've posted this I've not really had a chance to work on it more but I'm really starting to think that this is the only way to get it absolutely correct.

Comment: This question is now 5 years old and I've not really worked on it for 5 years. Hopefully there is. If you find a way, report back here and I'll try and make your answer the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that since iOS 4 `UIImage *image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];` strips the geolocation out. To solve this problem you have to use the original photo path to get access to the full image metadata. With something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:referenceURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        NSDictionary *metadata = rep.metadata;
        NSLog(@"%@", metadata);

        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage] ;

        if (iref) {
            self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // error handling
    }];
```

The output should be something like:

```
{
    ColorModel = RGB;
    DPIHeight = 72;
    DPIWidth = 72;
    Depth = 8;
    Orientation = 6;
    PixelHeight = 1936;
    PixelWidth = 2592;
    "{Exif}" =     {
        ApertureValue = "2.970854";
        BrightnessValue = "1.115874";
        ColorSpace = 1;
        ComponentsConfiguration =         (
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        );
        DateTimeDigitized = "2012:07:14 21:55:05";
        DateTimeOriginal = "2012:07:14 21:55:05";
        ExifVersion =         (
            2,
            2,
            1
        );
        ExposureMode = 0;
        ExposureProgram = 2;
        ExposureTime = "0.06666667";
        FNumber = "2.8";
        Flash = 24;
        FlashPixVersion =         (
            1,
            0
        );
        FocalLength = "3.85";
        ISOSpeedRatings =         (
            200
        );
        MeteringMode = 5;
        PixelXDimension = 2592;
        PixelYDimension = 1936;
        SceneCaptureType = 0;
        SensingMethod = 2;
        Sharpness = 2;
        ShutterSpeedValue = "3.9112";
        SubjectArea =         (
            1295,
            967,
            699,
            696
        );
        WhiteBalance = 0;
    };
    "{GPS}" =     {
        Altitude = "1167.528";
        AltitudeRef = 0;
        ImgDirection = "278.8303";
        ImgDirectionRef = T;
        Latitude = "15.8235";
        LatitudeRef = S;
        Longitude = "47.99416666666666";
        LongitudeRef = W;
        TimeStamp = "00:55:04.59";
    };
    "{TIFF}" =     {
        DateTime = "2012:07:14 21:55:05";
        Make = Apple;
        Model = "iPhone 4";
        Orientation = 6;
        ResolutionUnit = 2;
        Software = "5.1.1";
        XResolution = 72;
        YResolution = 72;
        "_YCbCrPositioning" = 1;
    };
}
```

Comment: I need to check this out Carlos, looks promising!

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. I'm guessing you are pulling from the Photo Library, not directly from the camera. [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]; return nil for Camera images. I DO have a UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL if I read from the Photo Library.

Comment: Confirming that `info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]` is `nil` for photos taken with the `UIImagePickerController`'s camera.

Comment: This is working on images picked from camera roll in iOS7. However the GPS info may be empty since device GPS signals may not be available all the time when user is taking pictures. I'm not using UIImagePickerController to take picture so I can't comment on that part...

Answer (score 13):

We have worked a lot with the camera and `UIImagePickerController` and, at least up to and including iOS 5.1.1, it does not return location data in the metadata for either photos or videos shot with `UIImagePickerController`.

It doesn't matter whether location services is enabled for the Camera app or not; this controls the Camera app's use of location services, not the camera function within `UIImagePickerController`.

Your app will need to use the `CLLocation` class to get the location and then add it to the image or video returned from the camera. Whether your app can get the location will depend on whether the user authorizes access to location services for your app. And note that the user can disable location services for you app (or entirely for the device) at any time via `Settings > Location` Services.

Comment: This is partly true. Apple does strip out GPS data from EXIF. But you can open the RAW data of the image, and parse the data yourself.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro do you have a sample code for how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You're not using the image data from the camera in the code you've posted, you've generated a JPEG representation of it, which would essentially discard all the metadata.  Use `image.CGImage` like Caleb suggested.

Also:

> This is also for a commercial product so I cannot use http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/.

The author quite clearly states that commercial licensing is available.

Comment: 1) But image.CGImage is a CGImageRef, not a CFDataRef. I both get a compiler warning, which if ignored results in a "unrecognized selector" crash. 2) I'm an unfunded startup right now, once funded I'll gladly look at commercial libraries!

Answer (score 3):

Can't say I've needed to do exactly this in my own stuff, but from the docs it seems pretty clear that if you're using `UIImagePickerController` you can get the image that the user just took from the `-imagePicker:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate method. Use the key `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` to get the image.

Once you've got the image, you should be able to access its properties, including EXIF data, as described in [QA1654 Accessing image properties with ImageIO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1654/_index.html). To create the CGImageSource, I'd look at `CGImageSourceCreateWithData()` and use the data that you get from the UIImage's `CGImage` method. Once you've got the image source, you can access the various attributes via `CGImageSourceCopyProperties()`.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't give the latitude/longitude. I'll edit my question so you can see my source and results...

Answer (score 1):

As point out by [Chris Markle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367004/1107651), Apple does strip out GPS data from EXIF. But you can open the RAW data of the image, and parse the data yourself or use a third party lib to do that, for [example](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/).

Here is a sample code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]
             resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

                 ALAssetRepresentation *image_representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                 NSUInteger size = (NSUInteger)image_representation.size;
                 // create a buffer to hold image data
                 uint8_t *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(size);
                 NSUInteger length = [image_representation getBytes:buffer fromOffset: 0.0  length:size error:nil];

                 if (length != 0)  {

                     // buffer -> NSData object; free buffer afterwards
                     NSData *adata = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:size freeWhenDone:YES];

                     EXFJpeg* jpegScanner = [[EXFJpeg alloc] init];
                     [jpegScanner scanImageData: adata];
                     EXFMetaData* exifData = jpegScanner.exifMetaData;

                     id latitudeValue = [exifData tagValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_GPSLatitude]];
                     id longitudeValue = [exifData tagValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_GPSLongitude]];
                     id datetime = [exifData tagValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_DateTime]];
                     id t = [exifData tagValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_Model]];

                     self.locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Local: %@ - %@",latitudeValue,longitudeValue];
                     self.dateLavel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data: %@", datetime];

                 }
                 else {
                     NSLog(@"image_representation buffer length == 0");
                 }
             }
            failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"couldn't get asset: %@", error);
            }
     ];
}
```

Comment: I think you are reading from the Camera Roll, I need to read the data from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

This is tested on iOS 8 and works for videos so it should work similarly for photos with a few tweaks.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *videoUrl = (NSURL *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSString *moviePath = [videoUrl path];

    if ( UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath) ) {

        ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        [assetLibrary assetForURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

            CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
            NSLog(@"Location Meta: %@", location);

        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Video Date Error: %@", error);
        }];

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you are reading from the Camera Roll, I need to read the data from the camera.

Comment: @PaulCezanne If that's the case, you're better off just using CLLocationManager to obtain the GPS Coordinates separately after image capture.

Comment: Yup, hence my accepted answer. Except that I need to do it DURING image capture, so I'll do it on a background task, recording the TIMES and locations, then afterwards match up the best location with the image capture time. You need to do it this because the person might hit the shutter and then, while the camera is still open, move to a new location to try and spoof the system. Not a big deal since there is a workaround but it adds complexity. And also, it has been 2+ years since I asked the question and sadly, that project is on hold. A shame, it was a good project, still is actually!

Comment: @PaulCezanne so I guess best option to retrieve the GPS coordinates is to save to camera roll and pull it later right? Using CoreLocation seems heavy.

Comment: It is up to you. Saving to Camera Roll means the user will see it in Camera Roll.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift** answer:

```
import AssetsLibrary
import CoreLocation


// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        defer {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        guard picker.sourceType == .photoLibrary else {
            return
        }
        guard let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL else {
            return
        }

        let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
        library.asset(for: url, resultBlock: { (asset) in
            guard let coordinate = asset?.value(forProperty: ALAssetPropertyLocation) as? CLLocation else {
                return
            }
            print("\(coordinate)")

            // Getting human-readable address.
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(coordinate, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
                guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                    return
                }
                print("\(placemark.addressDictionary)")
            })
        }, failureBlock: { (error: Error?) in
            print("Unable to read metadata: \(error)")
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your UIImagePickerController delegate, do the following:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  NSDictionary *metadata = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];

  // metadata now contains all the image metadata.  Extract GPS data from here.
}
```

Comment: I'll check it out, but I'm not hopeful. I think I looked at that already, not sure...

Comment: That will only work if the image HAS metadata.  It may not if the image doesn't have GPS data or the iPhone camera was set to not save GPS coordinates when the picture was taken.

Comment: No GPS info in there, sorry. Didn't think so.

Comment: I checked Settings/Location Services. Camera was set to ON so I don't think that that was the issue, but is there somehwhere else to check? If so, please leave an answer, can't award the bounty to a comment...

Comment: I just sync'd my phone with my laptop, my images do have GPS location data in them, so I know that Camera does it.

Comment: how to add GPS to image taken from camera could you help me