# Mapping Photos Geolocaton

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, location

I am a complete noob when it comes to Objective C. Does anyone have any good references on how to extract the geolocation metadata from the photo and turn those into coordinates that I can read and map into the mapkit?

Any insight you could give me would be tremendously helpful!

Comment: Some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302250/reading-the-gps-data-from-the-image-returned-by-the-camera-in-ios-iphone

Comment: Right now I am reading some examples of how to extract the EXIF data, but I am confused if the photos are being saved with EXIF data automatically, or I should append them to the photo metadata as I save them?