# Unable to get location while loading all photo from photolibrary using ALAsserLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, cllocation, photolibrary

I would like to load all photos from Photolibrary with their timestamp and location.

I am using this code to achieve this:

```
CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];// Get location here
NSDate *timeStamp = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];// Get timeStmap
NSLog(@"Picture location: %@ on Date: %@",location.description, timeStamp);
```

Here is Problems:

1. I am able to get `timestmap` accurate. But problem with `location`, I am unable to get accurate location, while my location service is enabled.
2. In `iOS 7` for some photos it is returning location details but not accurate, always returning current location with current time stamp.
3. In iOS 6.1 also not able to get `location`, `timestmap` is accurate but not `location`. And for most of the photos `location` data is `nil`.

Here is log for `iOS 7`

```
2014-01-02 11:56:38.231 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-09-30 10:36:10 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:38.284 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-10-03 07:23:51 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:38.432 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44866667,+78.38300000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:38 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-10-07 13:18:26 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:38.552 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44850000,+78.38300000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:38 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-10-07 13:18:38 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:38.664 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44850000,+78.38300000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:38 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-10-07 13:18:39 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:38.701 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-10-09 05:36:12 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:38.735 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-10-09 06:55:21 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:38.860 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44866667,+78.38300000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:38 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-10-15 12:00:53 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:38.895 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-10-15 12:01:18 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.013 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44883333,+78.38300000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:39 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-10-21 09:57:25 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.132 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44900000,+78.38283333> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:39 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-10-21 09:57:45 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.163 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-10-31 09:17:45 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.233 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-10-31 11:42:13 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.350 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44887167,+78.38291167> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:39 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-11-14 10:07:26 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.480 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44873333,+78.38298833> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:39 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-11-14 10:09:54 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.519 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-11-22 04:56:20 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.577 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-11-22 04:56:49 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.607 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-11-22 05:01:16 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.635 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-11-22 05:01:21 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.700 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-11-22 05:01:30 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.732 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-11-22 05:02:35 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.848 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44944667,+78.38292000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:39 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-11-25 10:40:15 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:39.964 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44930333,+78.38288000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:39 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-11-25 10:40:42 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:40.080 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44957833,+78.38255333> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:40 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-11-26 10:20:52 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:40.197 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44989500,+78.38241667> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:40 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-11-26 10:21:17 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:40.231 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: (null) on Date: 2013-11-26 12:44:59 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:40.348 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44842000,+78.38305500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:40 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-12-11 10:52:40 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:40.465 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44820333,+78.38291167> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:40 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-12-11 10:53:59 +0000
2014-01-02 11:56:40.583 TestApp[898:60b] Picture location: <+17.44842167,+78.38308667> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/2/14, 11:56:40 AM India Standard Time on Date: 2013-12-11 10:54:25 +0000
```

Comment: did you save any pics using any of the app thats installed in your iPad except default camera?

Comment: @Ramshad accurate `location` issue has been resolved. I tested yesterday, It is working properly. One thing I am not getting why for some photos my `location` data is null. As you ask, if we save photos using any of the app. Is it cause of `location` data be null ?

Comment: this is the root of my comment ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166575/photo-taken-with-camera-does-not-contain-any-alasset-metadata