# get the creationDate from a image of the cameraRoll in swift

Tags: swift, image, date, uiviewcontroller, imageview

im developing an application which works with the creationDate of the images and i would like to know if there is any way to get the creationDate from the images in the camera roll, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 
`- imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate method, look at the media info. From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys), you can use `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata` to get the info about a newly capture photo. If you are working from the Camera Roll, you should refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116527/iphone-ios-how-to-extract-photo-metadata-and-geotagging-info-from-a-camera-roll) and the official `ALAssetsLibrary` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/).