# Getting coordinates of image in IOS

Tags: ios, ios5, ios5.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Do I Get The Correct Latitude and Longitude From An Uploaded iPhone Photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319465/how-do-i-get-the-correct-latitude-and-longitude-from-an-uploaded-iphone-photo)

Does anyone know how you can get the coordinates at which an image was taken in IOS. If you go to the Photos app in IOS you can see where photos were taken and I'd like to get that information when I load a photo in my app.

Comment: See the question and answer [How Do I Get The Correct Latitude and Longitude From An Uploaded iPhone Photo?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9319465/1318452)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
```

Comment: Not sure I gave enough info. I'm using the UIImagePickerController and then on the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate I handle the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo callback. But I'm not sure how to go from there. I can get the image in this method, but I don't know where to get the coordinates for the image.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I take the photo and, as soon as I get the image back, I check the assets and ALAssetPropertyLocation is not present, even with permission already granted to the app in question (and to the Camera app, FWIW), on iOS 5.x on an iPhone 4 and iPad 3rd gen.